# KivyMD 2.0.1 error importing _window_sdl2

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

KivyMD 2.0.1.dev0, python 3.9. when I try to run the code the debugger gives this error **sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _window_sdl2: The specified module was not found**. but this module is installed on Python Interpreter.
What could have caused this error? if someone helps, I will be very grateful
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]